# Omit, React.ComponentProps, and React Final Form's FieldProps produce an unexpected type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-final-form

Consider this code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Field, FieldProps, FieldRenderProps } from "react-final-form";

type SelectFieldProps<T extends string> = {
    options: { label: string; value: T }[]
} & FieldProps<T, FieldRenderProps<T>>;

function SelectField<T extends string = string>(props: SelectFieldProps<T>) {
    return (
        <Field<T> name={props.name}>
            {({ input }) => 
                <select {...input}>
                    {props.options.map(option => 
                        <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                            {option.label}
                        </option>
                    )}
                </select>
            }
        </Field>
    )
}

type FruitSelectProps = Omit<React.ComponentProps<typeof SelectField>, "options">

function FruitSelectField(props: FruitSelectProps) {
    const fruitOptions = [
        { value: "apple", label: "Apple"},
        { value: "banana", label: "Banana"},
        { value: "cherry", label: "Cherry"},
    ]

    return <SelectField {...props} options={fruitOptions} />
}
```

(Here's a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQokscA3nAGLQgA0HwWAGwAmvdv2EAFYmFSjxQ7ADshWKFIgy4AXzhES5SnhgBaAsEXIBprrTp0YATzBY4AZUFZ8YwUPUyAPAAqcFgAHjBYyuioMFDmAOYAfHAAvKx0cJlwGjDAEIqoAFyscALIAEaCxTFxivE0cABulgCuWMXBWgDaALp0OgBkfD5+qEFyPkoqatJjgYmJ9HQELYr4eYpuHl7yQSHhkULRsQmpcDUJiQAUYLPF7gKeMN6Ss0GJAJTpWXCUMC1QTZXDI-LL+F5Cd5wCwgLApFi3DSoAB0MKwWkSINBoJYVzY5jALXgWi+KWSWOxlP8qG28BYyIZBKJGIplLZrERMmROQ2KJAyDAVx5+VS5PZ4tB-mFmwA1lgHPDpcjmgI2joVW1FWBcvlla10ZiJUacUqypUBFpWcbsf4APTSw3W0EfS1OuB2mmPfCO8Wuqm2iE+uAffp2RzODhQFrAGAPJ6jM4AeRAMf82CMyIAwiRIIpIjBRv5w1gIAQtl7nvJErwyNLUGRMctVusRewozG4zsfDc7pHo7HaaMviwKbh8jFdO2YIntbyzl0rZk2Br2uQBWBHmReGaquQAIJgDdYMhabiLkor4pkcrICwWLelCq7sgAIVv75PZ7Zy-1V9wAAtVCgBwHx3AQr0zQCoGAz8KT6Ck-gBTZ-E7SsfFYBlkU5VAdDreEiH7GcdQKHRbUxS0mzWYiOGQRpoBjLA237TgoFIK5hwQrB-kBOBgTZcEuGyRRXBacoUxgeExwKCBHmRAQIHiFkjVxFh-1vIRHhEsSYxJUVePPfiCEE-ItPE+E1OUTTRPEpS3TBJiO1pCFoWQWEUjIAiYzIOAyIMiV-HKIkYHyRJTNTW1ApgYLFCDI07SM1jYspF0-RtAMuCDEMtCAA))

`FruitSelectProps` is being evaluated to

```
type FruitSelectProps = {
    [x: string]: any;
    [x: number]: any;
}
```

However, the correct typing should be `type FruitSelectProps = FieldProps<unknown, FieldRenderProps<unknown>>` or something similar.

What's going on? How can I fix this?

If I change `SelectFieldProps` to

```
type SelectFieldProps<T extends string> = {
    options: { label: string; value: T }[]
};
```

it works as expected. However, I do need it, so this is not really an option.

Comment: I think I found the reason why this is happening: https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/blob/main/typescript/index.d.ts#L121. FieldProps is an interface with `{ [otherProps]: any }` defined in it.

Comment: Here's this issue documented: https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/issues/874